# popper.js : How to migrate Popper.Defaults.modifiers.computeStyle.gpuAcceleration in v2?

Tags: javascript, popper.js

After migration to popper.js v2:

```
<script>
    Popper.Defaults.modifiers.computeStyle.gpuAcceleration = !(window.devicePixelRatio < 1.5 && /Win/.test(navigator.platform));
</script>
```

This throws an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modifiers' of undefined

As I see in the Popper source code the `gpuAcceleration` is still a subject of the configuration, but I can find the way how to access it.

There is nothing in the migration guide https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/migration-guide/ about this.